# Can you target an event listener to a specific Chrome Alarm?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, alarms

I'm trying to create a Chrome Extension that uses two different alarms, using the Chrome Alarms API. I want to create two specific listeners, each handled by a different alarm:

```
chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(function(timer) {
  reminder.displayMessage();
});

chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(function(walk) {
  reminder.displayWalkMessage();
});


chrome.alarms.create('timer', {
  delayInMinutes: 5,
  periodInMinutes: parseInt(time)
});


chrome.alarms.create('walk', {
  delayInMinutes: 30,
  periodInMinutes: 60
});
```

The problem I'm having is that it seems when one alarm fires, both event handlers are triggered.  Is there a way to specify which handler gets triggered by an alarm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace the two event listeners with a single event listener:

```
chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(function(alarm) {
  if(alarm.name === "timer"){
      reminder.displayMessage();
  }
  else if(alarm.name === "walk"){
      reminder.displayWalkMessage();
  }
});
```

The argument to the callback function of [`onAlarm`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/alarms#event-onAlarm) is an object of type [`alarm`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/alarms#type-Alarm).